# Global partial behaviour in Controllers

Tags: php, templates, symfony

I have a base controller for most of the controllers in my app like so:

```
class BaseController extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
{
    /**
     * 
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction($partial = false)
    {
            $this->partial = $partial;
        $this->currentAction = 'index';

        return $this->r();
    }
}
```

This is accompanied by a pack of templates that can be either full html pages with a layout or just the content. This is done by a line in the templates:

```
{% extends this.partial ? "SomeProject:_base:partial.html.twig" : "SomeProject::layout.html.twig" %}
```

(where `this` is a the controller reference).

These templates can then be rendered in other controllers without the duplication of layout via.

```
{% render 'SomeProject:SomeController:index' with  { "partial":true }  %}
```

My problem with this approach is:

1. Every action that needs to be partial controller must have a `$partial` argument. Since most actions have the potential to be partial, all the controllers must be sprinkled with it.
2. Every potentially partial action must have the `$this->partial = $partial` line, which can be easily forgotten.

It there a cleaner way by using some Symfony or Twig magic (overriding the `render` tag etc. ). For getting rid of the above problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and digging around in the internals I've come up with an elegant solution.

The answer is to build an Event Listener (covered in [Symfony2 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)). More precisely: a Controller Listener with the meat of the class looking like below. This allows for transparent handling of partial without any changes made to the Controller code.

```
class ControllerListener
{
    /**
     *
     * @param BaseController $ctrl
     * @param Request $request
     * @return BaseController 
     */
    public function injectPartial($ctrl,Request $request)
    {
        if ($ctrl instanceof BaseController)
        {
            if ($request->get("partial",false))
                $ctrl->setPartial($request->get ("partial"));
        }
        return $ctrl;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $ctrl = $event->getController();
        $ctrl[0] = $this->injectPartial($ctrl[0], $event->getRequest());
        $event->setController($ctrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have overridden the render method in most of my controllers in order to inject some standard variables into my templates.  It seems to work well but all it will do for you will be to make rendering a template from a controller a bit easier since you won't have to explicitly pass $this to the template.

I am not so sure passing a reference to the controller is such a good idea.  For your example at least, Just passing partial would seem to be all you need.

Do you really need to give your templates this partial capability?  Seems easier to just have two templates (one for the page and one for the partial).  But perhaps your use case requires it.

Comment: Overriding `render` is a perfectly good way to go for setting standard variables for Twig files, and that exactly where I set the `this` variable - I've found that this speeds up development somewhat because I have many method at my fingertips (and yes - I do realize that this can lead to too much logic in the View).

Comment: I do have two templates for my files, but in a project of several hundred views, it really is quite overkill to make a de-facto useless file if the result can be achieved in another fashion.